What are the known or hypothesized pathways for the $\Lambda^0 \rightarrow n + \pi^0$ reaction?
Note to the Gentle Reader
I have found over the years that the moderators herein often offer negative marks, but when doing so they seldom offer helpful commentary. I am genuine in my desire to learn the physics. I am uncertain about these matters. I seek clarification, guidance and mentorship.
Context
I surmise, perhaps incorrectly, that flavour changing by neutral currents is a violation of the standard model. This is discussed in [10], where the OP asks, "Can flavor changing neutral currents occur," and where SuperCiocia answers. SuperCiocia states, on the one hand that, "Tree-level flavour changing neutral currents are not allowed in the Standard Model"; on the other hand,  SuperCiocia states, on the one hand that, "A "flavour changing current" is a process featuring the violation of quark flavour conservation. When mediated by a neutral particle such as the $Z^0$ boson (or a photon), they do not entail a net charge exchange and are hence called "flavour changing neutral currents."  Perhaps, I am dogmatic, but these statements seem at odds.
I understand that the Cabibbo-Kobayashi-Maskawa (CKM) matrix is theoretically a unitary matrix which contains information on the strength of the flavour-changing weak interaction. My understanding is that the formalism countenances, and only countenances, decay routes due to the charged weak interaction. It is important to note that though the CKM matrix ought be unitary in theory, it is not strictly unitary empirically. This indicates to me the possibility that other decay routes ought be included. Specifically, the possibility that neutral-current interactions need to be countenanced.
With this in mind, I would like to focus attention on $\Lambda^0 \rightarrow n + \pi^0$ reaction. I will interspers questions into my answer. I hope for illuminating questions, comments, and answers in the comments. I also hope for lengthy answers that correct any misunderstanding that I have or that otherwise round out the gestalt of the question.
The question posed herein is also relevant to the quetion in [30], where the OP asks, "Strange quark decay into two down quarks and an anti-down quark." (cf, Equation 2 herein).
Question
What are the known or hypothesized pathways for the $\Lambda^0 \rightarrow n + \pi^0$ reaction?
Answer

A decay route due to neutral-current interaction

$$
\Lambda^0 \rightarrow uds \rightarrow ud(\underbrace{Z^0}_\text{virtual}d)  \rightarrow (udd)( Z^0  ) \rightarrow (udd)\left( u\overline{u}  \right) \rightarrow n + \pi^0
\tag{1}
$$

Another decay route due to neutral-current interaction

$$
\Lambda^0 \rightarrow uds \rightarrow ud(\underbrace{Z^0}_\text{virtual}d)  \rightarrow (udd)( Z^0  ) \rightarrow (udd)\left(  d\overline{d}  \right) \rightarrow n + \pi^0
\tag{2}
$$

Decay route due to charged-current interactions

$$
\Lambda^0 \rightarrow uds 
\rightarrow 
ud(\underbrace{W^-}_\text{virtual}u)  
\rightarrow 
(ud)( d\overline{u} u) 
\rightarrow 
(udd)( \overline{u} u) 
\rightarrow 
n + \pi^0
\tag{3}
$$
Follow-on question 1) Is the decay by a virtual neutral-current interaction (i.e. Equation 1) allowed or disallowed by the Standard Model? How come?
Follow-on question 2) Is the decay by a virtual neutral-current interaction (i.e. Equation 2) allowed or disallowed by the Standard Model?  How come?
Follow-on question 3) Is the decay by a virtual charged-current interaction (i.e. Equation 3) allowed or disallowed by the Standard Model? How come?
Follow-on question 4) What other types of decays would work?
Note, since I am not concerned with the reaction with a proton product,  I heretofore  omitted the reaction
$$
\Lambda^0 \rightarrow uds 
\rightarrow 
ud(\underbrace{W^-}_\text{virtual}u)  
\rightarrow 
(uud)( d\overline{u} ) 
\rightarrow 
(uud)( d\overline{u} ) 
\rightarrow 
p + \pi^-
\tag{4}
$$
Bibliography
[10] Can flavor changing neutral currents occur
[20] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabibbo%E2%80%93Kobayashi%E2%80%93Maskawa_matrix
[30] Strange quark decay into two down quarks and an anti-down quark

Feynman diagrams are a more illuminating way to illustrate the pathway than the scheme you have right now

Yes you would. FCNC are allowed in the SM, but are highly suppressed by virtue of the fact they go through loops consisting of charged W intermediaries, not a Z, whose SM couplings must be flavor diagonal...

@Cosmas Zachos, Can you give a citation for these loops?

Any serious book on the SM: M Schwartz, Li & Cheng, Peskin & Schroeder....

An introductory HEP lecture on FCNC would have dispelled most of the interlocking confusions involved.
The basic facts are that strangeness violation must go through the charged current (W) at tree level, as only CKM mixing can elicit it. At tree level, the Z (and the photon) is necessarily flavor-diagonal.
But, at highly suppressed loop levels, several CKM matrices may combine to FCNC, in an effective vertex always involving internal Ws, but also ultimately involving external Zs or γs.  So FCNY do not violate the SM, but are condemned to suppressed significance, except in fortuitous special domains.


SuperCiocia states, on the one hand that, "Tree-level flavour changing neutral currents are not allowed in the Standard Model"; on the other hand,  SuperCiocia states, on the one hand that, "A "flavour changing current" is a process featuring the violation of quark flavour conservation. When mediated by a neutral particle such as the $Z^0$ boson (or a photon), they do not entail a net charge exchange and are hence called "flavour changing neutral currents."  Perhaps, I am dogmatic, but these statements seem at odds.

He is right, but he neglects to emphasize the Z or γ
need not be mediators, but even external lines. The virtual Ws involved are necessary and ineluctable for such processes.

This indicates to me the possibility that other decay routes ought be included. Specifically, the possibility that neutral-current interactions need to be countenanced.

Countenanced but promptly dismissed. The suppression factors involved in them are staggering, and a good course in HEP should have the student estimate them (astronomical factors).
$\Lambda^0 \rightarrow n + \pi^0$ goes through the CC process (3) of yours, in reality, whereas your (1) and (2) are "allowed", albeit absurdly small--I am too lazy to estimate the order of magnitude suppressions involving extra W propagators
Specifically, in your obscure language, the penguin diagram might possibly present as
$$
\Lambda^0 \rightarrow uds \rightarrow ud(\underbrace{W^-u}_\text{virtual})    \rightarrow (udd)( \underbrace{Z^0}_\text{virtual}  ) \\ \rightarrow (udd)\left( u\overline{u}  \right) \rightarrow n + \pi^0
\tag{1}
$$
and similarly for (2). Appreciate the alternate path to
virtual $W^-c$ instead of $W^-u$, with GIM-cancelling CKM elements.

I'm looking now on youtube for a good video to watch.  If anyone has a link to a lecture on the topic, then kindly add a comment to the same.

Might transpose this to light quarks…
